# in Django ORM, how to get a count in a reverse set query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have these three models:

```
class Member (models.Model):
    FederationID = models.FloatField(unique=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    eye = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    hair = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    Address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photos)
    Rank = models.ManyToManyField('Rank', through='Promotion')
    Unit = models.ManyToManyField('Unit', through='Assignment')

class Genre(models.Model):
    ShortName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.LongName + ' (' + self.ShortName + ')'


class Career(models.Model):
    ShortName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.LongName + ' (' + self.ShortName + ')'


class Rank(models.Model):
    RANK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('O', 'Officer'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('V', 'Civilian'),
        ('C', 'Cadet'),
    )
    ShortName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LongName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RANK_TYPE_CHOICES, default='O')
    Genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Career = models.ForeignKey(Career, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Photos, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.LongName + ' (' + self.Career.LongName + ') from ' + self.Genre.LongName


class Promotion(models.Model):
    Rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    PromotionDate = models.DateField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Member.User.first_name + ' ' + self.Member.User.last_name + ' promoted to ' + self.Rank.LongName + ' on ' + str(self.PromotionDate)
```

I created a many-to-many relationship between Rank and Member via Promotion.
In the model Rank, I have the `Type` field.

I need a count and group by the type field for each member on their latest Promotion.

like this: `{'officer':4, 'enlisted':2, 'Civilian':12}`

I added this to get the rank for each member:

```
self.promotion_set.latest('PromotionDate').Rank
```

but I need this for the group.

I appreciate any wisdom in here. Thanks

Comment: How about `Member.objects.filter(Rank__Type='O').count()` ?

Comment: There are ways of doing this with subqueries, but to be honest I'd be tempted to denormalize this a bit, by setting a `current_rank` attribute on Member. Presumably promotions happen infrequently, so you can update the rank at that point. This would make the query much simpler.